# How can I fill two or more adjacent spaces on a QO panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Is there a better way to fill two or more adjacent spaces on a Square-D "QO" panel than to use two QOFPs side by side?

I am aware of the QOFP from Square D but it is just for a single space:

[image]

That's all I can find.

I would have thought a 2-space blank would be an obvious thing to exist... and possibly SqD makes something else which is harder to find information on. Or could there be plates from other sources that would work?

I know there are very clear rules on which breakers could be used in what panel, but I'm not sure if a "non electrical accessory" (if that is a meaningful distinction) would also be as carefully regulated, so maybe something from another manufacturer could be used (or not).

I can presumably place several of these single plates next to each other but my recollection from another project is that even in a single space they don't fit particularly well (too small / sloppy).

Comment: You might be able to 3d print a filler? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/213187/3d-print-blank-space-filler-for-panel

Answer (score 10):

That's a common complaint. Every maker's filler plates are a) flimsy, b) expensive, and c) hard to find.

Fortunately, Square D also sells a much more robust filler plate which solves all these problems, called the QO120.

[image]

They're sold *everywhere*, latch onto bus stabs, and aesthetically look - well, they *actually are* breakers!

I'm not joking.  "Actual breakers" *really are* my go-to for filling empty panel spaces, because it solves the flimsy problem, and they're just more available.  My local lumber supply stocks these, they do not stock blank covers.

As for cost, since I'll probably be fitting a circuit in the future anyway, 120V/20A breakers are a pretty safe choice because if you're adding a circuit you can always choose to use #12 wire.  And they can be handle-tied for 240V/20A circuits which do not involve neutral.  (though a handle-tie is another procurement bug-hunt).

Comment: On the one hand, there aren't very many ways left that you can legitimately use a non-AFCI breaker in a residential setting in 2021. On the other hand, a real breaker is *half* the price of a QO1DB so even if you can't use it and have to replace it with an AFCI breaker when you really want to use the space, you still come out ahead. Also, you've pictured a QO*1*20 not QO220 (not enough chars to edit).

Answer (score 8):

Generally, if you have spaces broken out in the deadfront, you also have breakers that filled those spaces.

You can leave the breaker(s) in place, connected to nothing, preferably labeled as such, if you have reconfigured the panel to no longer need those breakers at present. They store just as well there as on a shelf, and are harder to lose.

Comment: Also leave the disconnected breakers turned **off**.

Comment: I had a bunch of circuits moved to a backup generator panel - sped'c QO for the new panel so the breakers in the existing QO panels could just move over, instead of paying for a bunch of new breakers. But as it turns out having about a dozen blanking plates scattered around is super janky, so in hindsight that doesn't seem like such a good idea after all.

Answer (score 7):

### Since you have QO...there's a third way :)

If you find filler plates too flimsy/awkward, and putting a regular breaker there too error-prone, Square-D has you covered too!  Simply get a QO1DB *dummy breaker* (or three) and use it in place of the filler plate.  (These clip to the busbar just like a regular QO, but can be identified by their utter lack of a handle or load screw.)

Comment: Too bad QO isn't into the *UL Classified* thing... it'd be awesome if they made a QCH1DB, QBR1DB, QQP1DB, QQ1DB, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I can answer at least part of this, I asked Square D and they said:

> Unfortunately, we just offer a single filler plates for branch
> breakers, QOFP like you mentioned or if this one old load center maybe
> you will need a QO1FP filler plate for each space, I recommend you
> install one per space, below is the link with a video and the
> installation bulletin.
>
> FAQ https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/FA109110/

(The FAQ is a little tangential, it just discusses how a different single-space filler plate is needed for certain older panels.)